# how to send array of object to server. Asp.Net Core 3.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, post, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-405

I am trying to send array of object to web Api post ActionResult method.
**my array of objects looks like this**

```
'[{"TitleFeature":"عنوان یک","ValueFeature":"مقداریک","IdProduct":"1"},{"TitleFeature":"عنوان یک","ValueFeature":"مقداریک","IdProduct":"1"}]'
```

[image]

**my function JS looks like this**

```
const uri = '/api/Feature/PostFeatures';
        const baseURL = window.location.origin;
        var dataFeature = getFeature();
        var features = JSON.stringify(dataFeature);

        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: (baseURL + uri),
            data: features,
        });
```

**my Controller.cs is looks like this**

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Feature>> PostFeatures([FromBody] List<Feature> features)
    {
        if (features != null)
            foreach (var item in features)
            {
                _context.features.Add(item);
            }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
```

I use Role Based authorization and this is my role:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class FeatureController : ControllerBase
```

how to fix error 405?

Comment: Try replacing your data in the ajax request with this: `data: {features}`, note the curly brackets. And ensure CORS policy is configured in your Startup.cs

Comment: I replace WebAPI Controller to razore Controller and implement CORS. I passing data at view to contrroller, but there is a new problem. I can't get **List of Feature** in parameter of function. I got the null value from the view. @HassanMonjezi

Answer (score 0):

The `405` error means that you have entered the URL but the http request does not match, so if there is no route attribute on your action method, you can try to change the ajax request address to `.../api/Feature`